# Pry Error: Cannot find local context. Did you use `binding.pry`?

Tags: ruby, pry

Why am I getting this pry error?

```
[36] pry(main)> s = "pry"
Error: Cannot find local context. Did you use `binding.pry`?
```

It works fine in this screencast http://pryrepl.org/

Comment: I admit I got the same error today for the first time in my life. I seem to install latest `pry`. This error appears when one tries to assign value to `s`, or use `s` in any other context (sic!) I believe, this is latest release bug of _pry_.  `a = 'pry'` will work for you.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It seems that `s`, `c` and `n` are reserved commands on the pry-nav gem, found [here](https://github.com/nixme/pry-nav), that help you to step through bindings.

`Pry.commands.alias_command 'c', 'continue'`
`Pry.commands.alias_command 's', 'step'`
`Pry.commands.alias_command 'n', 'next'`

They are set up by default but can be removed by putting:

`Pry::Commands.delete 'c'`
`Pry::Commands.delete 'n'`
`Pry::Commands.delete 's'`

in a file called `.pryrc` in your root directory.

Comment: Yes, looks like this is relatively new.

Comment: And it's stuff like this that makes me prefer plain old `debugger`.

Comment: `f` seems to be reserved as well

Comment: Useful for removing the `next` command that is a Ruby keyword